# Google Drive copy file to shared folder - directly

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-shared-folder

I have a folder on "my drive" that I want to move or copy to the folder "Kai" which is located in "Shared with me".

[image: cannot copy]

Dragging a folder from the left sidepanel into the folder of the shared area works, if I choose the shared folder beforehand:

[image: folder moving works]

But as I said, I would like to **copy a file** directly to a shared folder.

Answer (score 3):

I achieved the same by adding the Shared folder to My Drive.
[image: Add to Dy Drive]

After that I could simply 'Move to...' my files to that folder.

Found the solution [here](http://digitalwriting101.net/content/how-to-put-a-file-into-a-shared-collection-on-google-docs/).

Answer (score 1):

The Shared with Me folder is only for files that other people have shared with you.   You do not control what is put in it:  other people so, when they share files with you.

Tell us why you are trying to put a copy of the file into that location, and we might be able to make suggestions about how to achieve the underlying goal.

Comment: A shared folder where I invite another person with permissions to edit this folder, is in my opinion a folder where these two persons can work on files together. This also includes adding new files to this folder.

Comment: Sorry but it is not a "shared folder".   It is a folder created by Google to contain files that are shared with you.   You are welcome, though, to create another folder called "Shared by Me"  (for example), and you will be able to save copies of your documents into that.

Comment: But see the 2nd clip above, I can drag and drop files there.

Answer (score -2):

In general you need to drag or copy from the main area to the left, or from the main area to the main area.  I believe you are trying to copy from the left.  (The left-hand sidebar functions like a table of contents.)

Comment: No, see the clips, I try to copy from the main area (local) to the main area (shared).

Comment: @Matheretter Okay, I guess I would install Google Drive on my computer and work in the file explorer.