# How can I copy big data from Shared folder on Google Drive without downloading them?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-shared-folder

Somebody has shared some folders with me in Google Drive and is planning to remove that sharing link. What he wants me to do is download all the data into my local system so that he can remove the shared link in future but I don't have enough space in my local system.

Is there any way I can copy the data from the shared folders in Google Drive to my Google Drive directly, instead of downloading the data first and then moving it to Google Drive?

Comment: Hey I think this link will solve your query [https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80907/google-drive-copy-file-to-shared-folder-directly](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80907/google-drive-copy-file-to-shared-folder-directly)

Answer (score 0):

For a file by file copy, on Google Drive on the web, select the files that you want to copy, right click over them, then select **Copy**. The copies should be added to your "My Drive". If needed, move the files to a folder.

To copy the whole folder on one pass, see [How to copy a shared folder into my own Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/120362/88163)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this with an external application.

1. Add the folder to "My Drive".
2. Open your account with a website: [www.multcloud.com](https://www.multcloud.com)
3. Find the folder - and create a copy into the account.

Effective in case there are many files.
Because normally you can not copy a folder, just files.

Answer (score -2):

I have tens of GB of data on "Google Drive", locally a smaller disk, and I don't need all that data at once. Steps:

1. in computer local client app [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) choose syncing only, choose folders in settings "Google Drive Application / Preferences / Google Drive / Sync only these folders" and then click OK
2. online in [Google Drive / Shared with me](https://drive.google.com/drive/shared-with-me) open context menu with mouse right click on item and choose item menu "Add to My Drive"
3. online in [Google Drive / My Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive) create new directory with button "New / Folder" with name "archive" and then move all new data there.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, actually this does the opposite that is being asked "don't download the files"

Comment: @Rubén you have right