# I transferred files between different Google Drive accounts and now they are dependent on each other

Tags: google-drive

I followed my own instructions for how to transfer folders between different Google Drives here [How to copy a shared folder into my own Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120362/how-to-copy-a-shared-folder-into-my-own-google-drive/149858#149858)

Basically, share a folder X from account A to B and give B edit rights. Now right-click on X again and a new option has appeared "Make B owner". This also removes A as owner and makes A *editor* of X.

I then changed A from *editor* to *viewer* and then, as A, deleted a file. Surprisingly, this was allowed and it also removed the file from B's account and put into B's Trash (as well as A's Trash).

Further information

- After changing the owner of X, the folder was "orphaned" on A's account. The only way to find its content is to search for a file in it. In other words, you can't start at the root of A's drive and browse to it.
- X consumes the quota on BOTH A's and B's account. This is weird. The deletion issue described above indicates that X is stored in just one account (although the fact that the deleted file ends up in both A's and B's trash says something different) but the quota usage indicates that X is duplicated.
- I have waited a couple of days in case there were some delays in updating the quota usage or similar.
- On A, X is listed under Shared with me.

How do I sort out this mess? I want X at account B, and only there, and recover my space at A.

---

Update 1 with more details:

If I look at X's share properties in account B, it is not shared and B is listed as the owner, just what you would expect. However, if I, from account B, look at file F **located in** X, A is listed as *owner* and B is listed as *editor*. This was **not** expected. A visualisation of the file hierarchy:

```
B/          (root folder for B)
B/X         (X is a folder and owned by B and not shared)
B/X/F       (F is a file and **is** shared and owned by A!! B only has editing rights.)
```

---

Update 2

From account A I tried to change the owner of F to B but that operation was not allowed.